# How to change the value of an MUI DatePicker in Jest (x-date-pickers)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, material-ui, datepicker

Regarding `{ DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'`:

I can't figure out how to change the value using Jest.

Here's my `DatePicker`-wrapper `DatePickerX`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import { de } from 'date-fns/locale';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';

export const DatePickerX: React.FC = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());

  const changeDate = (newDate: Date | null) => {
    if (newDate) {
      setDate(newDate);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
    <LocalizationProvider locale={de} dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <DatePicker
          label="datepicker_label"
          value={date}
          inputFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
          views={['year', 'month', 'day']}
          mask="____/__/__"
          onChange={changeDate}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField type="text"  {...params}  data-testid="textInput_testid" name="textInput_name"/>
          )}
        />
    </LocalizationProvider>
    </>

  );
}
```

This works perfectly fine on the UI.

Here are my attempts to change the date. All tests fail:

```
describe('change date picker value test 1', () => {
  test('use datepicker label; set string', async () => {
    render(<DatePickerX />);

    const input = screen.getByLabelText('datepicker_label');
    await act(async () => {
      await fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: '3000/01/01' } });
    });

    expect(screen.getByText('3000/01/01')).toBeVisible();
  });
  test('use text input; set string', async () => {
    render(<DatePickerX />);

    const input2 = screen.getByTestId('textInput_testid');
    await act(async () => {
      await fireEvent.change(input2, { target: { value: '3000/01/01' } });
    });

    expect(screen.getByText('3000/01/01')).toBeVisible();
  });

  test('use datepicker label; set date', async () => {
    render(<DatePickerX />);

    const input = screen.getByLabelText('datepicker_label');
    await act(async () => {
      await fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: new Date('3000/01/01') } });
    });

    expect(screen.getByText('3000/01/01')).toBeVisible();
  });

  test('use text input; set date', async () => {
    render(<DatePickerX />);

    const input2 = screen.getByTestId('textInput_testid');
    await act(async () => {
      await fireEvent.change(input2, { target: { value: new Date('3000/01/01') } });
    });

    expect(screen.getByText('3000/01/01')).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This was a pain to figure out but I finally got the solution. First off, you do not need to `await` the `fireEvent`. The following should work:

```
fireEvent.change(datePicker, {target: {value: '01/01/3000'}})
```

The `value` needs to be in the exact correct format when passing into `fireEvent`.

Now as for checking if the correct value was put into the date picker, you can use the `value` property of the `HTMLElement` returned by `getByLabelText`. I.e. `expect(input.value).toBe(expectedValue)`. The tricky part was getting `expectedValue`. You'd think it'd just be `'01 / 01 / 3000'`. But the rendering inputs some unexpected characters. I can't type them so
[here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnm2x.png).

You should be able to get the expected value using a debugger in your IDE (e.g. WebStorm) and copying and pasting it or by using dev tools in your web browser and copying the HTML element value
[as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rukw.png). You might also be able to copy and paste the unknown characters from this sample here:

```
'⁦⁨01⁩ / ⁨01⁩ / ⁨3000⁩⁩'
```

Here is my entire function for testing a DatePicker X component. Again, the unknown characters won't be visible here but you should be able to copy and paste them in the below code and they should show up in your text editor depending on what IDE you're using. I'm using WebStorm but they might show up in VS code too.

```
export const testDatePicker = async (labelText: string, day: number, month: number, year: number) => {
    const datePicker = screen.getByLabelText(labelText)
    const zeroPad = (num: number) => String(num).padStart(2, '0')
    const dayString = zeroPad(day)
    const monthString = zeroPad(month)
    const yearString = String(year)
    const dateText = `${monthString}/${dayString}/${yearString}`
    fireEvent.change(datePicker, {target: {value: dateText}})
    const datePickerValue = `⁦⁨${monthString}⁩ / ⁨${dayString}⁩ / ⁨${yearString}⁩⁩`
    expect(datePicker.value).toBe(datePickerValue)
}
```

Comment: Weird. For me `fireEvent.change(datePicker, {target: {value: '01/01/3000'}})` is not working at all.

Answer (score -1):

Before you render any component that has dependencies, is important to load those before.

So one of the issue that Test are failing could be that when you render the  component en each case the test runner is looking for the provider, adapters and the others dependencies.

To solve this you can use the **[jest.mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions)** function or **just  import them**

This is one of the example the doc link include.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Users from './users';

jest.mock('axios');

test('should fetch users', () => {
  const users = [{name: 'Bob'}];
  const resp = {data: users};
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp);

  // or you could use the following depending on your use case:
  // axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(resp))

  return Users.all().then(data => expect(data).toEqual(users));
})
```

Hope this help

Comment: `Before you render any component that has dependencies, is important to load those before.` I'm not sure what part you are talking about. Can you explain more?

Comment: This is why I share the jest link documentation for you to take a look and understand what I saying. Please notice on the **Jest.Mock()** function. This should help you.

All of this dependencies you should probable mock them.
`import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import { de } from 'date-fns/locale';`

Comment: So you're saying I should mock them. Thank you. That was not clear from your answer.
While mocking might be a solution, it's one I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

**Firstly:** I wanted to note that `@mui/lab` adapter should not be used together with `@mui/x` pickers. I'd suggest syncing those usages by changing your adapter import to `import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';` (based on [setup documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/#setup)).

**Secondly:** Have you checked which component is rendered during your test cases? I see that you are importing `DatePicker`, this component renders either `Desktop` or `Mobile` version of the picker depending on `desktopModeMediaQuery` prop. This rendering logic has some caveats in test environments, I'd suggested reading [testing caveats](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/#testing-caveats) doc section for more information on how to reach your desired result.

**Lastly:** Are those test cases you provided in the question your real project examples or just for illustration purposes? If they are real cases, I'd suggest thinking if it's worth testing behaviours, that are already tested by MUI on their end. Ideally, you should write tests asserting your own code.

**Edit:**
I've had a bit deeper investigation and manual testing of your cases and have the following conclusions:

3rd and 4th cases are invalid, because you can only set value on an `input` element, but those queries return a `TextField` root - div element.
2nd case does not work, because setting value to `new Date()` will cause the `toString` method to be called, which will not be in the format the component expects.

And as far as I can tell, your main issue might have been the usage of `getByText` query in the assertions. This query does not look for text in `input` element's value. Replacing it with `getByDisplayValue` seems to resolve your issue.

Please check [this example repository](https://github.com/LukasTy/mui-x-pickers-test-pickers/blob/main/src/components/DatePicker.test.tsx) with working examples.

Comment: The tests are demonstrations. The pickers are part of a form.

Comment: The testing caveats section only states, that the worst case for testing is rendering in Desktop mode. I'm not sure how this information shall help me.

Comment: @DarkTrick I just wanted to clarify that what is rendered in tests might differ from what you would expect (at least based on test cases—I'd assume, that you expect Desktop version to be rendered).
In any case, upon further investigation I think I've narrowed down your possible issue and have updated (edited) my answer with the findings.